# PHP/CSS button style with post queries

Tags: php, css, button

I am a newbie to PHP/CSS. I have coded a default.css button style and a php page with many processing buttons. The button style looks great on button with a url link. See code snippet below:

```
<form name="form" method="post">
<p class="button-style"><a href="importcsv.php">Import Sightings CSV</a></p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<p class="button-style"><a href="logbookentry.html">Enter New Sightings</a></p>
<br>
<p class="button-style"><a href="logbookentry.php">View Pre-logged Sightings</a></p>
<br>
```

However, when I use the same button style for run sql query button, the style is not uniform. See link http://conchslist.com/ziktest/logprocess.php

```
<p class="button-style"><input type="submit" name="button5" value="Run Makes 1" /></p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<p class="button-style"><input type="submit" name="button6" value="Run Makes 2" /></p>
<br>

$q = mysql_query("UPDATE AVDMASTER p, SightingsEntrytmp pp 
SET pp.MAKE = '1' WHERE pp.UNIQUEID = p.UNIQUEID AND p.MAKE = '0';")or die(mysql_error());
if($q) {
echo "successful";
}else {
echo "error";
}
} //if isset

if(isset($_POST['button6'])) {
$q = mysql_query("UPDATE SightingsEntrytmp p, AVDMASTER pp
SET pp.MAKE = '1' WHERE pp.UNIQUEID = p.UNIQUEID AND p.MAKE = '1';")or die(mysql_error());
if($q) {
echo "successful";
}else {
echo "error";
}
} //if isset'
```

It is probably really simple. But, how do I adjust the code to make the buttons uniform?

Thanks,

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

You have a second set of styles that targets `a` add a comma and add `input[type=submit]` so that the button is targeted as well.